# Firebase, Avoid Logged-in user to visit login page

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase hosting to make an app.
I have following code in my login.html page.

```
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
                firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                if (user) {
                    // user is loggin redirect to dashboard
                } else {
                    // No user is signed in. keep them here
                }
                });
        });

 $("#loginbtn").on("click",()=>{
                console.log("login");
                var errormessage="";
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var password =  $("#password").val();

                //client validate
                if(email.length == 0)
                errormessage+=("Enter a valid email.<br>");
                if(password.length == 0)
                errormessage+="Enter a valid password.<br>";
                if(errormessage.length==0){
                    $("#loginbtn").prop('disabled', true);
                    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
                    // Handle Errors here.
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    $("#loginbtn").prop('disabled', false);
                    showMessage(errorMessage);
                    // ...
                    });


                }else{
                    $("#signupbtn").prop('disabled', false);
                    showMessage(errormessage);
                }


            })
    </script>
```

However when user is logged in and user explicitly try to visit login.html by puting that in address bar the **login page is being displayed for few seconds** and then it redirects to dashboard page.
This leaves a bad user experience as login form is displayed for few seconds.
How can i acheive something like php sessions? where page redirects without rendering?
Can we connect cloud functions using "rewrites" to redirect user to other pages from backend? can a cloud function find if user is logged-in or not on client side?

(1) user Login with `signInWithEmailAndPassword()`.
(2) `AuthState` listener redirects to home url.
(3) user try to visit login.html page again.
(4) login.html page gets displayed for few seconds. **< problem.**
(5) `AuthState` listener redirects to home url.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking for!! You should add all the code connected to the problem. How do you log in, in particular.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec updated. my problem is that as i have implemented the auth state listner it contact firebase and get if user is logged in or not (this takes time) and in meanwhile the page is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your problem, you should wait that the promise returned by `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` is resolved to redirect your user.

As a matter of fact, `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` "asynchronously signs in" as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword), and returns a promise. This is why "it takes time" as you mention.

So you should do as follows to handle the login:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
   .then(userCredential => {
       //redirect your user here, because at this point the user is logged in.
   })
   .catch(error => {
            // Handle Errors here.
            // ...
    });
```

If you want to show a spinner or a progress bar during the asynchronous execution of the function, you can show it when you click on the `loginbtn` button and hide it in the `then()`.

Note that you don"t need to use `onAuthStateChanged()`, in this case, to detect when the user is logged in.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion however my problem is when user try to visit login.html page again after logging-in (Not when he is trying to login). 
--- 
(1) user sign in.
(2) user get redirected to home url.
(3) user try to visit login.html page again.
(4) login.html page show up for few seconds < problem
(5) then it get redirected to home url.

So in my case i don't user to view the login.html page as he is already logged in.

Comment: What happens if you remove the onAuthStateChanged listener function from the login page?

Comment: Login page is displayed.

Comment: Ok I understand. If the user **intentionally goes** to the login page you cannot avoid having the page being displayed the time it checks (through an asynchronous call to Firebase) if the user is already logged in or not. Or you have to rely on another mechanism implemented in your pages, e.g cookie or querystring variable, etc...